USB Loses Power when SVM Mode is enabled
Motherboard: B450M DS3H (rev. 1.x)
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600
When I enable SVM Mode in the advance cpu in the bios the USB ports loses power. I already tried installing another windows in another drive and the same issue occurs.
The first thing that happened is the BSOD Critical Process Died, and in the bios the nvme where windows is installed is missing, but reappeared after multiple restarts. Another BSOD appeared, I forgot the complete message, it contains WHEA. And then I run some diagnostics such as the windows built in memory tester, run a sfc command, and then chkdsk. I left while the system is doing chkdsk, and then I saw another error, REGISTRY ERROR, and was never able to boot the windows even selecting safe mode or any options. Then lastly I tried installing a new windows on another drive, but the keyboard dies as the windows installation (ext dvd) is loaded in the screen since I am attempting to repair or install windows, and I even tried plugging the dvd and keyboard on different USB ports. Until I reset the BIOS settings and was able to install windows in another drive and was able to boot successfully. I turned on the SVM Mode and the USB does not have any power in windows. No mouse no keyboard. Is my motherboard or cpu defective now? I was using SVM mode for years, and then this just happened. I can use the PC normally but I need the SVM Mode for android emulators. Thanks for anyone can help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
